# Flutter app not loading when I add Flutter_auth dependency

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

Whenever I try to add the Flutter_auth dependency to my flutter application in the pubspec.yaml file, the app no longer is able to compile. The app however loads fine without the dependency. I have tried creating a fresh Flutter project, running it before adding the dependency, and it runs fine, however after adding the dependency, the app no longer compiles. Odd because I am not changing any lines of code in the actual app.

I am using visual studio code, and attached is a screen recording of the issue at hand. I tried adding the dependency manually, and through the terminal, neither allowed the app to compile. I have also tried running flutter clean in the terminal to clear any cache in the flutter dependencies section.

Please take a look at the screen recording for more details on the flutter version and which other dependencies I am trying to add. [Screen Recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l6i23e7DbEmOoeumL2AgNwvAp_5law5f/view?usp=sharing)

I tried to run the flutter app as a project, running the main.dart file, and I expected the app to compile and launch the debug app, however when I added the firebase_auth dependency, the app no longer launched successfully. When I removed the dependency, the app compiled just fine. Without any changes to the code of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Config app in firebase console, Download `googleInfo-plist` file to correct location.

Add `initializeApp()` method in void `main()`:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Check the installation steps on the [start firebase documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios) and [authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start) to see if you are missing any steps